# Prometheus cAdvisor - How could I see metrics for containers rather than host

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

I'm following this [guide](https://stefanprodan.com/2016/a-monitoring-solution-for-docker-hosts-containers-and-containerized-services/) to setup cadvisor+prometheus+Grafana to monitor docker containers. Everything looks fine except I cannot find metrics in container level (host metrics shows fine). For instance, If I retrieve "container_memory_cache" in prometheus, it returns the following results"

```
container_memory_cache{id="/",instance="cadvisor:8080",job="cadvisor"}
```

"id" dimension is null, and there is no "name" dimension. By checking more, I tried to run rest APIs of cAdvisor to retrieve container information by using container id/name,  but still no luck:

```
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
02e385dc1bf1        grafana/grafana           "/run.sh"                18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   grafana
30ae6527facb        prom/node-exporter        "/bin/node_exporte..."   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       9100/tcp                 nodeexporter
927f0144f8c5        google/cadvisor:v0.27.1   "/usr/bin/cadvisor..."   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   cadvisor
4c277db6d796        prom/prometheus           "/bin/prometheus -..."   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   prometheus
b169c96dad3e        prom/alertmanager         "/bin/alertmanager..."   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp   alertmanager
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1.3/containers/02e385dc1bf1
failed to get container "/02e385dc1bf1" with error: unknown container "/02e385dc1bf1"
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1.3/events/grafana
[]
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]#

[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1.3/containers/grafana
failed to get container "/grafana" with error: unknown container "/grafana"
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v2.1/
Supported request types: "appmetrics,attributes,events,machine,machinestats,ps,spec,stats,storage,summary,version"
[root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v2.1/events/
[]
```

Here's cadvisor configuration from docker-compose.yml:

```
cadvisor:
  image: google/cadvisor:v0.27.1
  container_name: cadvisor
  volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/run:/var/run:rw
    - /sys:/sys:ro
    - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
  restart: unless-stopped
  expose:
    - 8080
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  networks:
    - monitor-net
  labels:
    org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
 ......
```

cadvisor log:

```
 [root@ip-172-31-56-244 dockprom]# docker logs cadvisor
 I1009 09:28:39.904951       1 storagedriver.go:50] Caching stats in memory for 2m0s
 I1009 09:28:39.905178       1 manager.go:149] cAdvisor running in container: "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu"
 W1009 09:28:39.933801       1 manager.go:157] unable to connect to Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp [::1]:15441: getsockopt: connection refused
 W1009 09:28:39.933995       1 manager.go:166] unable to connect to CRI-O api service: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fcrio.sock/info: dial unix /var/run/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory
 I1009 09:28:39.965342       1 fs.go:139] Filesystem UUIDs: map[]
 I1009 09:28:39.965362       1 fs.go:140] Filesystem partitions: map[tmpfs:{mountpoint:/dev major:0 minor:47 fsType:tmpfs blockSize:0} /dev/xvda1:{mountpoint:/var/lib/docker/overlay2 major:202 minor:1 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} shm:{mountpoint:/   rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/663cfebcdcb5c83740441d225a90546e4368789d676d6b6086d59fdcb5bdfe1f/shm major:0 minor:31 fsType:tmpfs blockSize:0}]
 I1009 09:28:39.971298       1 info.go:51] Couldn't collect info from any of the files in "/rootfs/etc/machine-id,/var/lib/dbus/machine-id"
 I1009 09:28:39.971390       1 manager.go:216] Machine: {NumCores:2 CpuFrequency:2394312 MemoryCapacity:8373006336 HugePages:[{PageSize:2048 NumPages:0}] MachineID: SystemUUID:EC20823C-306D-BF65-BC34-A40C692B43A6    BootID:2db18d19-659b-493f-b3b5-7980fd48d301 Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/xvda1 DeviceMajor:202 DeviceMinor:1 Capacity:105553080320 Type:vfs Inodes:6553600 HasInodes:true} {Device:shm DeviceMajor:0 DeviceMinor:31 Capacity:67108864 Type:vfs    Inodes:1022095 HasInodes:true} {Device:overlay DeviceMajor:0 DeviceMinor:30 Capacity:105553080320 Type:vfs Inodes:6553600 HasInodes:true} {Device:tmpfs DeviceMajor:0 DeviceMinor:47 Capacity:4186501120 Type:vfs Inodes:1022095 HasInodes:true}]    DiskMap:map[202:0:{Name:xvda Major:202 Minor:0 Size:107374182400 Scheduler:noop}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:br-169495c710b6 MacAddress:02:42:7d:01:a4:0d Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:eth0 MacAddress:12:79:be:fa:a6:d2 Speed:0 Mtu:9001}] Topology:[{Id:0    Memory:8373006336 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction    Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]}] Caches:[{Size:31457280 Type:Unified Level:3}]}] CloudProvider:AWS InstanceType:t2.large InstanceID:i-0e3ac492ad4c0b5f6}
 I1009 09:28:39.972406       1 manager.go:222] Version: {KernelVersion:4.9.43-17.39.amzn1.x86_64 ContainerOsVersion:Alpine Linux v3.4 DockerVersion:17.03.2-ce DockerAPIVersion:1.27 CadvisorVersion:v0.27.1 CadvisorRevision:cda62a4}
 I1009 09:28:39.984490       1 factory.go:355] Registering Docker factory
 W1009 09:28:39.984547       1 manager.go:265] Registration of the rkt container factory failed: unable to communicate with Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp [::1]:15441: getsockopt: connection refused
 W1009 09:28:39.984704       1 manager.go:276] Registration of the crio container factory failed: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fcrio.sock/info: dial unix /var/run/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory
 I1009 09:28:39.984735       1 factory.go:54] Registering systemd factory
 I1009 09:28:39.985581       1 factory.go:86] Registering Raw factory
 I1009 09:28:39.986558       1 manager.go:1140] Started watching for new ooms in manager
 I1009 09:28:39.987201       1 manager.go:311] Starting recovery of all containers
 I1009 09:28:39.989175       1 manager.go:316] Recovery completed
 I1009 09:28:39.994765       1 cadvisor.go:159] Starting cAdvisor version: v0.27.1-cda62a4 on port 8080
```

Comment: The cadvisor config seems okay. Can you see some errors in the cadvisor logs? `docker logs cadvisor`

Comment: @AndreasJägle thanks for looking. I've attached cadvisor logs. there is an error regarding conection refused to there is an error of connection refused to Rkt api service, but as per [#1757](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1757) : it's an expected one, so I have no idea what's wrong in my environment

Answer (score 1):

Updating docker version to  17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 fix the issue